# Space of bounded continuous functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $V$ denote the space of bounded continuous functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$. Enumerate the rationals by $r_1,r_2,\ldots$. Define the inner product on $V$ by
$$\langle f,g \rangle = \sum \frac{1}{2^k}f(r_k) \overline{g(r_k)}$$

The question is whether $V$ endowed with this inner product becomes a Hilbert space.

It is fairly easy to check the above operation is indeed an inner product, but I got stuck about the completeness part. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Personally, I'm having a very hard time proving that the above operation is an inner product. For instance, I'm having a hard time parsing what $\langle \sin; \cos\rangle$ is.

Comment: I think you need to add a factor of $2^{-n}$ or something. As it is, the norm of $f(x) = 1$ is infinity.

Comment: i have fixed the statement now @paulblartmathcop

Comment: As a side remark, what you define is simply the inner product of $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mu)$, where $\mu=\sum_k 2^{-k}\delta_{r_k}$. Of course $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in that space, but it is easy to construct elements that don't have a continuous representative (see the answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Hilbert space. Define
$$
f_n(x) = \max(0, \min(nx,1)).
$$
Then $f_n(x) \to 1$ for $x>0$ and $f_n(x)=0$ for all $x<0$. However $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in the given norm. Let $n>m\ge1$. Then
$$
\|f_n-f_m\|^2 = \sum_{k: \ r_k \in (0,\frac1m)} 2^{-k} |f_n(r_k)-f_m(r_k)|^2
\le \sum_{k: \ r_k \in (0,\frac1m)} 2^{-k}.
$$
It remains to show that the right-hand side converges to zero for $m\to\infty$. Take $g$ with $g(x)=1$ for all $x$. Then
$$
1 = \|g\|^2 \ge  \sum_{k: \ r_k \in (0,1)} 2^{-k} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{k: \ r_k \in [\frac1{i+1},\frac1i)} 2^{-k}.
$$
The sum $\sum_{k: \ r_k \in (0,\frac1m)} 2^{-k}$ is a tail of this converging series, hence $\sum_{k: \ r_k \in (0,\frac1m)} 2^{-k} \to 0$ for $m\to\infty$.
Thus, $(f_n)$ is Cauchy. The sequence converges pointwise on the rationals to a function that cannot be extended to be a continuous function.

Comment: Perhaps a simpler way to see that $\sum_{k : r_k \in (0,\frac{1}{m})} 2^{-k}$ converges to zero for $m \to \infty$ is as follows. Given $\epsilon > 0$, fix any $N$ such that $\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}2^{-k} < \epsilon$. Then it suffices to choose $m$ large enough so that the interval $(0,\frac{1}{m})$ is disjoint from $R_N := \{r_k : k \leq N\}$. But $R_N$ is a finite set, so obviously it's possible to do this; just choose $m$ so that $1/m$ is smaller than the smallest positive element of $R_N$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not an inner product.  It is not defined when the sum diverges, which it will in all but trivial cases.

Comment: i have fixed the statement now. Sorry for the confusion.